# Using Office.js is it possible to define the position and size of a taskpane?

Tags: office-js

In VSTO you could specify where and size...

I'm guessing this isn't implemented in Office.js but wondered if anyone had found ways to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per documentation on [Office Add-ins XML manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/form) you don't have any control over the size of task pane add-in. There are two properties related to add-in window size: "RequestedHeight" and "RequestedWidth", but they are for different types of add-in (content, Outlook read view, etc.). As for position, this is not controllable at all. Unfortunately you would be forced to use what Office.js Add-in manifest able to offer.

Answer (score 2):

Office.js does not support specifying the size or position of the taskpane. You also cannot configure this on the manifest. the previous answer is only valid for "Content" Add-ins. Please vote or add this request to our uservoice channel https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/category/169836-add-in-general-shared

thanks!